# Método excluir não é chamado quando clico em um commandButton

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um botão excluir que fica dentro de uma coluna do `dataTable` e quando clico no mesmo o método que é responsável pela exclusão do usuário não é chamado.

dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{usuarioBean.listaUsuario}" id="usuarioTable"
var="usuario" style="" emptyMessage="Nenhuma Usuário Encontrado. "
rows="5" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
```

Botão Excluir:

```
<b:commandButton icon="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" value=""
look="danger" style="margin-left:10px" ajax="true"
update="frmPrin" title="Excluir" actionListener="#{usuarioBean.excluir(usuario)}">
</b:commandButton>
```

Método excluir no MB:

```
public void excluir(Usuario usuario) {
        System.err.println("Metodo Excluir");

        try {
            UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
            usuarioDAO.excluir(usuario);

            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Usuario excluido com sucesso");
            usuario = new Usuario();
            listarUsuarios();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao excluir usuário");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Método Excluir no DAO:

```
public void excluir(Usuario usuario) {
        System.out.println("<METODO EXCLUIR CHAMADO");
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.delete(usuario);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    }
```

O escopo do MB é `@SessionScoped`

Comment: `actionListener="#{usuarioBean.excluir(usuario}` está faltando um ) , coloque e testa novamente.

Comment: Foi um erro na pergunta só, no código estava certo e mesmo assim o método não está sendo chamado

Comment: tentou adicionar o process="@this" no botão?

Comment: Eu estou usando `BootsFaces` não tem o process pra colocar nos botões

Comment: Este componente está dentro do mesmo form?

Comment: Está sim, eu tentei de tudo e não consegui resolver acho que é um problema com o BootsFaces

Comment: Pois quando uso o Primefaces funciona

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, já tentou usar só action?

Comment: Coloca no commandButton o ajax=false.

Comment: @Douglas Se você quiser responder, essa é uma solução. Eu tinha me esquecido de responder essa pergunta após solucionar o erro

Answer (score 0):

No seu `commandButton` mude o `ajax`:

```
ajax="false"
```